# Convert specific column to float in list by Python

Tags: python, string, list, converters

I have a list like :

```
[['1', '6', '192.168.4.118', '1605', '', '115.85.145.5', '80', '', '60', '0.000000000', '0x0010', 'Jun 15, 2010 18:27:57.490835000', '0.000000000'], 

['2', '6','115.85.145.5', '80', '', '192.168.4.118', '1605', '', '1514', '0.002365000', '0x0010', 'Jun 15, 2010 18:27:57.493200000', '0.002365000'], 

['3', '6', '115.85.145.5', '80', '', '192.168.4.118', '1605', '', '1514', '0.003513000', '0x0018', 'Jun 15, 2010 18:27:57.496713000', '0.005878000']]
```

And I want to convert specific column to float but I get error (for example the fourth column).

Here I tried this code:

```
for x in data:
    try:
        yield float(x)
    except ValueError:
        yield x
```

and I got this error:

```
File "read csv file.py", line 17
  except ValueError:
                     ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

or while I was using this simple code:

```
float (data [:][3])
```

to convert only the column 3 (fourth column) it was giving me error.

Please suggest me a way to store all of my data in variable which can contain float and string together.

Comment: I believe you can use numpy.astype

Comment: Are these Python lists or numpy arrays?

Comment: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html

Comment: You are using both spaces and tabs in your code. Please only use one (preferably 4 spaces as per [PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)). I believe this will fix your IndentationError problem.

Comment: you just want to change the fourth element in each sublist?

Comment: Are you trying to mutate the original list, get a new list where column N is converted to float, or just get every value from column N as a float?

Comment: I want to have a list which contain string and float together, for example I know the third column is IP address or the eleventh column is the TCP flag and they are not numbers so I will not touch it but as my list is string (by default) I just want to change specific columns to float (such as fourth column which is the port number or first column which is the packet number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After fixing the indentation errors as suggested above;

**convert an individual column**

```
data = [['1', '6', '192.168.4.118', '1605', '', '115.85.145.5', '80', '',
         '60', '0.000000000', '0x0010', 'Jun 15, 2010 18:27:57.490835000', '0.000000000'],
        ['2', '6','115.85.145.5', '80', '', '192.168.4.118', '1605', '', '1514',
         '0.002365000', '0x0010', 'Jun 15, 2010 18:27:57.493200000', '0.002365000'],
        ['3', '6', '115.85.145.5', '80', '', '192.168.4.118', '1605', '', '1514',
         '0.003513000', '0x0018', 'Jun 15, 2010 18:27:57.496713000', '0.005878000']]

for thing in data:
    thing[3] = float(thing[3])
```

**convert all *numbers* to floats**

```
def convert(sequence):
    for item in sequence:
        try:
            yield float(item)
        except ValueError as e:
            yield item

new = [list(convert(sublist)) for sublist in data]
# or
new = [[item for item in convert(sublist)] for sublist in data]
```